# Python gzip omit the original filename and timestamp

Tags: python, gzip, md5sum

Folks,
  I am generating an md5sum of a gzip file.  Technically, each time its compressing the same file, but the resulting md5sum is different.  How do I tell it to use the `-n` flag to omit the original filename and timestamp?

```
f_in = open(tmpFile, 'rb')
f_out = gzip.open(uploadFile, 'wb')
f_out.writelines(f_in)
f_out.close()
f_in.close()
```

Thanks!

Comment: How do you calculate the `md5` value? Do you invoke `md5` or `md5sum` via shell? This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131220/get-md5-hash-of-big-files-in-python

Comment: I calculate like this: `md5hash = hashlib.md5(open(file).read()).hexdigest()`

Comment: The value of `open(file).read()` most definitely only depends on file's contents and not name. Are you sure you upload files with the same content? same EOL characters? Also, try `open(file, 'rb')` for binary mode.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14004771/1180620

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `GzipFile` class allows you to explicitly provide the filename and the timestamp for the header.

E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import gzip

f = open('out.gz', 'wb')
gz = gzip.GzipFile('', 'wb', 9, f, 0.)
gz.write(str.encode('this is a test'))
gz.close()
f.close()
```

This will produce a gzip header with no filename and a modification time of zero, meaning no modification time per the RFC 1952 standard for gzip.

Comment: im not sure how to have it be blank... and where to insert it in the code snip above

Comment: Im not sure how to translate ` if discernible; otherwise, it defaults to the empty string, and in this case the original filename is not included in the header` from the docs... https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/gzip.html

Comment: If you provide the empty string as the filename, then the header will not include a filename at all.  As opposed to having a filename in the header that is an empty string.  Subtle difference.

Comment: does not work for me - gz still changes every run. at least the time seams to be now()

Comment: Just tried it again, and made the code portable to python 2 and python 3. Still writes the exact same gzip file every time, with a timestamp of zero. Not a timestamp of now. Copy exactly the code from my answer and test it.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to write utf-8 text to a gz file without a filename in the header, here's a way to do this:

```
import gzip, io

ofile = open("./stuff.txt.gz", 'wb')
ogzfile = gzip.GzipFile('', 'w', 9, ofile, 0.)
ogztextfile = io.TextIOWrapper(ogzfile, 'utf-8')

ogztextfile.write("Зарегистрируйтесь сейчас на\nДесятую Международную\nКонференцию")

ogztextfile.close()
ogzfile.close()
ofile.close()
```